# Primefaces enum output facet updates wrong

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, enums

I'm facing some problems using a primefaces cell editing table. So, I have a datatable, which contains an editable column. This datatable is populated through a list of jpa entity.

Focusing on wich matters, my editable cell, has an outputText in the output facet and a selectOneMenu in the input facet, which is populated by an enum.

My problem is that, datatable is correctly loaded at beginning, I can successfully edit the wanted field, selectOneMenu is correctly populated with enum. If I choose an option in the selectOneMenu, it gets fine, HOWEVER when I click outside the datatable (to quit editing mode), it gets a wrong value, since it gets the code, and it should get description.

My code:

**Enum**:

```
public enum EnumSimNao implements DetalheDominioEnum {
    /**
    * Sim
    */
    S("Sim"),
    /**
    * Não
    */
    N("Não");
```

Enum has a getter that refreshes the value based in some services. It always get those values from the service. I've tested it and the values are right here. When I say description, I mean "Sim" or "Nao", and the codes are respectively "S" or "N". From the database it comes a code, that is associated with enum through an @Enumerated attribute in an jpa entity. When I have `#{tp.respostaObrigatoria.description}` it returns me "Sim" or "Não" based on the returned code.

```
    public String getDescription() {
    DetalheEstaticoDominioEnumHelper.INSTANCE.fillDescriptions(this);
    return description == null ? defaultDescription : description;
}

@Override
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

**xhtml**:

```
                        <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{tp.respostaObrigatoria.description}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{tp.respostaObrigatoria}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{Factories.enumSimNao}" var="simNao"
                                    itemLabel="#{simNao.description}" itemValue="#{simNao}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
```

**tp** is an entity whcih comes from a list that comes from backing bean:

So, when I edit the cell, I can see both descriptions ("Sim" or "Nao"), but when I exit the edit mode it shows "S" or "N". Finally, if I refresh the page, it gets the correct description value I had choose.

Do you have any tip?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong values"? What is it returning instead of what you're expecting? Also, post the getter for for `enumSimNao` here

Comment: I've edited the question, so that you can understand what should it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces 3.5 has this bug which apparently was filed under this issue http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6116 and solved in version 3.5.15 which is only available on Elite version. Version 4.0 seems to have this fixed.

I found a workaround for 3.5 which involves re-rendering the form enclosing the datatable which is working fine for me.
What you need to do is to use an ajax event listener inside the selectOneMenu component which triggers the render of the form like this:

```
<p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output">
        <h:outputText
            value="#{tp.respostaObrigatoria.description}" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{tp.respostaObrigatoria}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{Factories.enumSimNao}" var="simNao"
                itemLabel="#{simNao.description}" itemValue="#{simNao}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{bean.submit}" render="@form" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```